# Azure append_blob_from_path

Tags: python, azure

I'm using the Azure append blob service with the append_blob_from_path function.

Is there any way to check if the append was successful? The reason I want this is because after I appended a file i wish to delete it.

Just doing

```
append_blob_service.append_blob_from_path(self.container_name, blob_name, file_name)
delete_file(file_name)
```

seems to cause delete_file to sometimes delete a file that append_blob_service is trying to upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I test [`append_blob_from_path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.appendblobservice.appendblobservice?view=azure-python#append-blob-from-path-container-name--blob-name--file-path--validate-content-false--maxsize-condition-none--progress-callback-none--lease-id-none--timeout-none--if-modified-since-none--if-unmodified-since-none--if-match-none--if-none-match-none--cpk-none-) on my side, the method is sync, I am not sure why you got the issue.

I use `azure-storage-blob 2.1.0` and `Python 3.7.4`, you could check the code sample as below, in my sample, I append a file with the size of `50 MB(52428800 B)`, use the `progress_callback func(current or total)`, the process is clear enough.

```
from azure.storage.blob import AppendBlobService
import os

account_name = "xxxxxxxxx"
account_key = "xxxxxxxxx"

append_blob_service = AppendBlobService(account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key)


def generate_progress_callback():
    def progress_callback(current, total):
        print('({}, {})'.format(current, total))

    return progress_callback


append_blob_service.append_blob_from_path(container_name="test1", blob_name="test123.txt",
                                          file_path=r"C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\test1234.txt",
                                          progress_callback=generate_progress_callback())

print("hello")
path = r"C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\test1234.txt"
if os.path.exists(path):
    os.remove(path)
    print("delete file")
else:
    print("no such file:%s" % my_file)
```

**Result**:

[image]